# How to keep a bottom nav bar from being pushed up on keyboard shown

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

How can i create a sticky footer that wont be moved up with the view when the softkey keyboard popups up?

Below is an image example of my current setup and what i want to achieve.
I have a scrollview that contains my page content and a linearlayout that is aligned to the parent bottom that acts as a nav bar.

[image: Example of what i want it to do]

Problem is that when the keyboard popups, it pushes my entire view up, including the bottom nav section. **I do not want to disable** the automatic pushing up of the view (by setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`) but rather **exclude a single element from being pushed up**, my bottom nav bar.

I have tested the windowSoftInputMode fix but it hides my page content behind the keyboard.  Is there a way to have it continue pushing up the scrollview but not the bottom nav?  My other option was to set `visibility:gone` on keyboard up and then reshow it on keyboard down, but that seems overly complicated and not always reliable from what i read.

If anyone has any examples or suggestions, i'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: I am very late but I have posted an answer, so anyone facing this problem, please go through my answer once, it might save your time and energy.

Answer (score 25):

Either add this as scrollbar's XML attribute

> android:isScrollContainer="false"

or add this in Activity's tag in Manifest

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: You should probably use comments rather than ask questions in your answer.

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` on the manifest worked for my case

Answer (score 11):

I tried a lot of solutions found on SO and only adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" into the manifest for the activity worked for me:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
```

I include the associated layout because your solution is highly dependent on your layout, so this solution worked for me in this case:

```
  <RelativeLayout
     ...
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
           ...
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
             ...
            design:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've run into the same problem as OP and while `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` makes the keyboard cover the footer (which stays at the bottom of the screen), the ScrollView doesn't get pushed up and loses its scrolling ability, which means that in the end part of it are behind the keyboard and inaccessible.

Comment: Good point @Neph - I've also found that the solution is highly dependent on your entire view hierarchy and what works in one instance has undesirable consequences in another.

Comment: you r great! helped this

Answer (score 5):

Just add this line in your `onCreate`, When this option set the window not adjust for a shown input method. :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

Comment: Do this in the on the onCreate method of your activity. It will then apply to all fragments within that activity.

Answer (score 3):

I am very late to answer but I ran into same situation lately. I followed another approach to solve this issue and that was rather than using `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`, using `CoordinatorLayout` and having behavior applied to `BottomNavigtaionView` to show/hide it with scrolling to top or bottom (the same way we see CollapsingToolBar or AppBarLayout).

The built in behavior used for BottomNavigationView is `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"`

You can read all steps in detail from my [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314789/1055241).

P.S. I posted it as an answer rather than a comment because sometimes we just look for answers and ignore the comments and I believe it could be a good approach to solve this issue, so you should not ignore it and give it a read once. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a pretty similar problem with the differences that a) I wasn't using a ScrollView at first and b) the item I didn't want to move was a simple TextView.

Here's the answer I found: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970851/2016165)

What I did to fix it:

- Use `adjustResize`
- Use 4 Layouts: A surrounding one, 1 for the header, the ScrollView and 1 for your "bottom nav"
- Don't just rely on `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, while this will move your navigation bar to the bottom of the screen, it also means that the keyboard can move it up because of "adjustResize"
- Additionally use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in combination with `android:layout_below="@id/MyScrollView"` (so the layout will use up all the space it can get between the ScrollView and the bottom of the screen) and `android:gravity="bottom"` to simply have everything at the bottom of the layout.
- You might also be able to use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead of `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but I didn't fully test it like that.
- Like I said, this will make the "bottom nav" layout use up all the space it can get below the ScrollView. If you don't want that, e.g. because your "bottom nav" has a different color you don't want to be shown too much, try creating a surrounding RelativeLayout for "bottom nav" and another empty layout inside that can push "bottom nav" downwards. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize")

```
<application
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="false" />
    ...
</application>
```