# How to hide the BottomNavigationView below keyboard with adjustResize set

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, bottomnavigationview

According to the [material design spec](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs), when the keyboard appears, the `BottomNavigationView` should hide underneath it. However, if I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the Activity's manifest then the `BottomNavigationView` moves above the keyboard.

I need to set `adjustResize` to enable scrolling to the bottom of the screen while the keyboard is open. However, I do not want the `BottomNavigationView` to be visible. Can this be done?

How it currently looks:

[image]

The layout XML (in reality there would be a `FrameLayout` where the `EditText` is and the `EditText` would be inside it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Input"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No I didn't, but one suggestion was to hide everything behind the keyboard when a field is tapped on (including bottom nav bar) then when the user taps the screen above the keyboard or scrolls the keyboard just disappears. It's not great but I think it's a better user experience than the floating nav bar. The Spotify app does this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... If you find a solution, please tell me...

Comment: Hey All ! I have posted a new answer which actually solves this problem. Writing this comment as I am very late to answer and the answer with max votes doesn't really solves this problem may be that's why OP hasn't accepted it yet. So please go through my answer once.

Answer (score 54):

Add this to your activity in the manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

So like

```
<activity android:name=".feature.home.HomeActivity" 
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: This is a good thing to keep the bottom nav view to stick to bottom when keyboard opens but it doesn't allow scroll view to work.

Comment: this is not a solution for bottom navigation.

Comment: It clearly mentioned in the question that how to do that with adjustResize not with adjustPan.

Answer (score 7):

### Solution (or another way to do the same)

I have been through the exact same situation as OP stated, I had a `BottomNavigationView` obviously at the bottom of the screen and above that there was `ScrollView`.

> Now if we do `adjustPan` in activity then `BottomNavigationView` remains at bottom when keyboard appears but the scroll doesn't work.
>
> And if we do `adjustResize` then scroll works but BottomNavigationView gets pushed on top of keyboard.

I think below can be two approaches for the same.

**Approach 1**

Simply set the visibility to gone/visible on keyboard show/hide. It is quick work around for the same. You can get a listener for keyboard hide/show event in next approach it self.

To make it look interesting, you can try showing/hiding BottomNavigationView with some sort of animation.

**Approach 2**

Some better way (the material design way) would be using `CoordinatorLayout` and scrolling behavior (same as you might have seen `CollapsingToolBar`).

Below would be the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="@string/title"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    ------ Your Contents --------

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

That's it, now you can see the BottomNavigationView hiding/showing on scrolling to bottom and top etc. But there is another problem which you could face, in one scenario i.e. when keyboard is hidden, if the content is too small to scroll,

And the problem is that when keyboard opens and you scroll to the bottom which hides the BottomNavigationView, now if you press the back button keyboard hides but the BottomNavigationView still remains hidden. Now, as content is not scrollable, so if you try to scroll, it doesn't show BottomNavigationView. To reveal it again what you need to do is, make keyboard visible again and then scroll upwards, when BottomNavigationView is shown then press back button.

I tried to solve this problem this way,

Add a Global Listener to find out if keyboard is shown or hidden. The code I used here was, (it is in Kotlin, however you can easily convert it to the Java version if you need that)

```
private fun addKeyboardDetectListener(){
    val topView = window.decorView.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
    topView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val heightDifference = topView.rootView.height - topView.height
        if(heightDifference > dpToPx(this, 200F)){
            // keyboard shown
            Log.d(TAG, "keyboard shown")
        } else {
            // keyboard hidden
            Log.d(TAG, "keyboard hidden")
            val behavior = (navigation.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams).behavior as HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior
            behavior.slideUp(navigation)
        }
    }
}

fun dpToPx(context: Context, valueInDp: Float) : Float{
    val displayMetrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, displayMetrics)
}
```

And the last thing, if you use Support Library version 28.0.0 then you will see that  `behavior.slideUp(navigation)` method is protected, so you can't call it from your activity etc.

However Google's Android team has already made these methods public in new `material-components`. [Check this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/behavior/HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior.java) so just import material-components in your project and use this class instead.

Apart from it you can try some more experiments like programmatically calling slideUp or slideDown on keyboard hide/show etc.

P.S. I have spent good amount of time to come to this fully working approach, so thought to share it here, so that it could save someone's time.

Comment: It's good approach but for me When edit text gain focus keyboard is still shown unless user scrolls

Comment: @Nux When EditText gains focus, keyboard should display. Did you mean to say when EditText looses focus, keyboard still remains displayed?

Comment: thanks for response, It was just little mistake, Solved already

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution, which doesn't require `adjustSpan`, but it works only for `API >= 21`. You can detect if keyboard is shown/hidden by tracking system insets. Say you have `BottomNavigationView`, which is child of `LinearLayout` and you need to hide it when keyboard is shown:

```
> LinearLayout
  > ContentView
  > BottomNavigationView
```

All you need to do is to extend `LinearLayout` in such way:

```
public class KeyboardAwareLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public KeyboardAwareLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public KeyboardAwareLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public KeyboardAwareLinearLayout(Context context,
                                     @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public KeyboardAwareLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                     int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int index = 0; index < childCount; index++) {
            View view = getChildAt(index);
            if (view instanceof BottomNavigationView) {
                int bottom = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
                if (bottom >= ViewUtils.dpToPx(200)) {
                    view.setVisibility(GONE);
                } else {
                    view.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
        return insets;
    }
}
```

The idea is that when keyboard is shown, system insets are changed with pretty big `.bottom` value.

Answer (score 0):

In your "Manifest.xml"

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:exported="true"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> // <- just add this line
</activity>
```

1. When a text field gets focus, the system checks the keyboard's
   height.
2. With adjustPan, the system shifts the layout up to keep the text
   field visible.
3. When the keyboard hides, the layout goes back to normal.

This helps users see what they're typing without manual scrolling. Note that sometimes other options like `adjustResize` are better, depending on your app's content.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there's a simple approach:

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Some time copy paste from other layout will happen this.In my case i just remove  `tools:context="Your class name"` from layout file.Thanks

Answer (score -4):

As an *alternative* way with your `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` you can try this.

call this method from your `OnCreate`- once the keyboard is up you can change visibility of views that you don't need to show!
When keyboard is down display them again.

```
 public void checkKeyBoardUp(){
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int heightDiff = rootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

                if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is up...
                    whatEverView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }else{
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is down...
                    whatEverView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Its right solution but for proper check keyboard status, use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/920379)

Comment: This doesn't work: white space stay in the place of navbar

Comment: Better try with `View.GONE` rather than `View.INVISIBLE`